# How to show the badge of notification on the App Store icon in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I want to show the badge of notification on the App Store icon in iPhone after approving the update of application on the App Store.
Does developer has to do any thing for that badge of Notification or App Store will take care of it?
Please suggest me regarding it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't trigger this badge yourself.

The badge is updated once the user opens the App Store and the store checks for updates for all installed apps. If there are updates, the App Store will update this badge itself.

There's no central instance that triggers this badge, especially it is not "attached" to push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It's automatic, you don't have to do anything.